# Dependencies of dependencies in Gradle

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I am studying Gradle and I am trying to find best practices with it.

The project that I will describe is built successful. You can clone on GitHub, it is a eclipse/java project: https://github.com/pauloleitemoreira/GradleTests.git

Assume that I have a MainProject with some file modules dependencies that not belong to the MainProject.

**Project Structure**

```
x-MainProject
|        |
|        x-mainModule 
|
x-LibProject
|        |
|        x-libModule
|
x-BaseLibProject
         |
         x-baseLibModule
```

**MainProject/setting.gradle file:**

```
include ':mainModule'

include ':LibProject', ':LibProject:libModule'
project(':LibProject').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../LibProject')
project(':LibProject:libModule').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../LibProject/libModule')

/*???*/include ':BaseLibProject', ':BaseLibProject:baseLibModule'
/*???*/project(':BaseLibProject').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../BaseLibProject')
/*???*/project(':BaseLibProject:baseLibModule').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../BaseLibProject/baseLibModule')
```

**LibProject/setting.gradle file:**

```
include ':libModule'

include ':BaseLibProject', ':BaseLibProject:baseLibModule'
project(':BaseLibProject').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../BaseLibProject')
project(':BaseLibProject:baseLibModule').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../BaseLibProject/baseLibModule')
```

**BaseLibProject/setting.gradle file:**

```
include 'baseLibModule'
```

I noticed that only the MainProject/setting.gradle file is executed when Build. The others LibProject/setting.gradle and BaseLibProject/setting.gradle are not executed when I am building the MainProject.

I marked with `/*???*/` the lines that sound weird for me, because I suppose that libModule would have to know where are your dependencies. In my understanding, these lines isn't necessary and gradle could include BaseLibModule when LibModule is built. But unfortunately, if I take out these lines, the project won't build.

I was thinking if there is another place to put `project(':...').projectDir = new File...`, in a way to avoid to include Dependency of dependency files?

Answer (score 0):

[Build lifecycle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html#sec:settings_file) chapter in Gradle user guide explains how multi-project builds work. Simple version is that there is one `settings.gradle` in root project folder that defines what projects are included in build. Each project can have `build.gradle` (or the name can be different or the file may be missing).

Comment: I have already read some grade help files before post the questions.  I am not asking it.

Comment: What you want in your project is `settings.gradle` in root folder where you will include MainProject, LibProject, BaseLibProject, and their subproject. Currently you have several multi-project builds and they are re-using various directory trees. That's a pretty confusing setup that goes against usual conventions and causes your troubles. BTW: it's better to exclude `GradleTests/MainProject/.gradle` directory from versioning.

Comment: You have to consider that I can't change the folders of these libs.  These libs support others projects.

Comment: It sounds like you have independent projects and try to connect them in a way that is likely to cause troubles. Build outputs from your libraries and publish them in binary repository. Then your dependencies are expressed through these binary dependencies.